# What does this command line (`echo $1 | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f1`) do?

Tags: xargs, cut

I need to understand this command line:

```
file=`echo $1 | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f1`
```

Comment: Try https://explainshell.com/.

Answer (score 5):

It assigns a bit of a filename (possibly with a path) to the variable `file`.  Specifically, the bit before the first `.` character in the filename of the file itself. In other words, it takes something like `/some/path/hello.world` and parses out the `hello` bit.

A tip would be to run each part of the pipeline on the command line:

```
$ thing="/some/path/hello.world"

$ echo "$thing"
/some/path/hello.world

$ echo "$thing" | xargs -n 1 basename
hello.world

$ echo "$thing" | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f 1
hello
```

The backticks are used to for returning the output of the pipeline and assigning it to `file`.  The `$1` is the first argument on the command line (for whatever script or shell function this is part of).

It is likely that the only reason `xargs -n 1 basename` is used instead of plain `basename` is  that the `basename` utility doesn't read from standard input, but `xargs` does.

A shorter (and faster) version of the same thing in `bash` or `ksh93` would be

```
file=${1##*/}
file=${file%%.*}
```

Comment: Maybe also explain the possible consequences of failing to quote the `echo` argument properly (the string will be split into tokens and wildcards will be expanded, basically).

Answer (score 1):

The line extracts the filenames without extensions from paths provided via `$1` (the first argument to the script in which that line appears). The result is saved in the variable `file`.

Demo:

```
$ echo /etc/dhcpcd.conf ../foo/bar/filename.tar.gz | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f1
dhcpcd
filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `echo` and `xargs` is rather curious here.

`basename` takes a pathname on the command line, and outputs the final component of it (i.e. part after the last slash, usually). `xargs` just places words read from its input (the pipe) to the command line of `basename` here. So why not just use `basename $1`?

There is, however, a difference.

In `echo $1 | xargs -n 1 basename` if the parameter `$1` contains whitespace, `xargs` will split it on spaces, and call `basename` for each word separately. The end result will be that a part of the filename will be picked for *all* the words, as [Arminius showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358842/170373).

The other option, `basename $1`, would call `basename` only once (and fail in some nice ways due to word splitting.)

If the command is supposed to only handle one filename, it would be better written as:

```
file=$(basename "$1" | cut -d '.' -f 1)
```

With the quotes. (or using the suffix-stripping shell expansion `${file%%.*}` instead of the `cut` as [Kusalananda showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358844/170373).)

If, on the other hand, it's supposed to handle multiple file names, it might be cleaner to pass them using an array, or in the positional parameters (all of them, not just `$1`).

Answer (score 0):

The line stores the name of a file, without extension and path, in the variable `$file`.

In detail:

`echo $1` prints the first command line argument passed to the script, `xargs -n 1 basename` passes the echoed string as arguments to the command `basename`, which strips the path from the filename. 
`cut -d '.' -f1` removes the extension.

So, for example if you execute

```
echo directory/test.sh | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f1
```

the result (saved to `$file`) will be `test`.